# How to avoid the use of asInstanceOf while passing data between modules in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Consider the following situation:

```
class Program { }
object Program { }


object Generator{
    val program: Program = new Program

  def met = {
    val mychecker = Checker(program)
    mychecker.check
  }
}

trait Checker {
  val program: Program 
  def check
}

trait Order {
  val checker: Logic
  def met1: Nothing = checker.program
}

object Checker{
  def apply(p: Program) = new { 
    val program: p.type = p
  } with Logic { self =>
    object AnOrder extends {
      val checker: self.type = self     
    } with Order

    val order = AnOrder
  }

}

trait Logic extends Checker { self =>
  protected val order: Order { val checker: self.type }
  def check = order.met1
}

Generator.met
```

Here, I write `def met1: Nothing` so that you see my point, basically the type Program is different for the Generator and the Checker. So I get

> type mismatch; found : Order.this.checker.program.type (with
>   underlying type Playground.this.Program) required: Nothing

Now, my question is not about this error. I'd rather ask how you can avoid converting with `asInstanceOf` when you have two modules M1 and M2, one passes some data of type T to M2, which does some computation and then returns the very same datatype (up to this difference we see in the error).

How would you do so in the example above?

**Real world error**

As I explained in one of my comments the compiler won't get through more complicated instances of Program. See for instance [my project](https://github.com/rjraya/stainless/tree/typeerror) that you can't compile with sbt -> compile. You'll see that the terminationCache gives a type error due to the problem mentionned here and I need to use asInstanceOf.

Comment: first of all if you can define your own types like this type Program. or you can use case classes or case Object if it is not taking any parameter.now if you want to make some type generic then there are some ways you can do. the most simple way is to extend it with empty trait.

Comment: @RamanMishra I don't get very well what you're proposing actually...

Comment: You need to isolate the problem, not clear what you mean. Path-dependent types are created to be different, but I don't see any path-dependent types in your code.

Comment: please could the people who downvote also ask to close the question?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon no because there are already two answers and the help center says that in that case i cannot delete it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the question. I think you have either made a separate mistake and misattributed your error to the phantom symptom you describe in the question, or I have misunderstood you.

Here is a version of your posted code, with minor tweaks that appear to me to be unrelated to your question, that compiles just fine ([try it here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YjB4NTw8TRuOvgpbeX2IPw)):

```
class Program { }
object Program { }
trait Logic {}


object Generator{
    val program: Program = new Program

  def met = {
    val mychecker = Checker(program)
    mychecker.check
  }
}

trait Checker {
  val program: Program 
  def check
}

trait Order {
  val checker: Checker
  def met1: Program = checker.program
}

object Checker{
  def apply(p: Program) = new { 
    val program: p.type = p
  } with Checker { self =>
    object AnOrder extends {
      val checker: self.type = self     
    } with Order

    val order = AnOrder

    def check = println("check here")
  }

}

println("compiled OK")
```

Note that I have changed `def met1: Nothing` to `def met1: Program` and it works fine.

You asked:

> How you can avoid converting with asInstanceOf when you have two modules M1 and M2, one passes some data of type T to M2, which does some computation and then returns the very same datatype

I think that you do not need to use `asInstanceOf` when two modules M1 and M2 both interact with a common type, like `Program` in this case.

Comment: the error was just a way of showing that type M1.Program and M2.Program are different types. This then provokes that I cannot collect for instance type Program.FunDef in M2 and pass it to M1 since M1 will see type M2.Program.FunDef and will have to use asInstanceOf to convert it to M1.Program.FunDef. That is what I wanted to explain

Comment: M1.Program and M2.Program are not different types, as demonstrated by my example code. They are both the same class, `Program`.

Comment: The fact that your code compiles shows that for this simple case the compiler can see that the "underlying type" is the same. But if you inspect Generator.program by assigning it to a variable with wrong typing it will detect Generator.program.type and if you inspect the output of met1 you'll get Order.this.checker.program.type. these are afaik two different path-dependent types which in real applications (i can't point to my project) may not be detected at equal, thus requiring the use of asInstanceOf method

Comment: @Rodrigo Then post an example that actually illustrates your problem.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. If you have separate types `M1.Program` and `M2.Program`, then you will not be able to cast between them. However, if you have a single type `Program`, then casts will not be necessary. Perhaps if you could post an example showing your problem then things would be clearer.

Comment: As previous commenters have pointed out, it is difficult to answer your question as you do not clearly illustrate what your problem is. From looking at your code, the only issue I see is that the code looks over-complicated, as I don't see a reason to use the `p.type` or `self.type` (just use the base types) or the need to use early initializers (note that they will be gone in Scala 3).

Comment: You have updated your question to refer to https://github.com/rjraya/stainless/tree/typeerror and say that that (large) project exhibits the problem but that your example code in the question does not exhibit the problem. Sorry, but I don't have time to debug a large project. Please could you isolate the problem here if you want further help? I have voted to close the question for the reason "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.".

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly ignoring the code you've pasted, but to answer the question you asked in text, you can do something like this:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def someCommonMethod: Whatever
}

case class Something(foo: Int) extends MyTrait {
  def someCommonMethod: Whatever = ???
}

object M2 {
  def someComputation[T <: MyTrait](t: T): T = {
    //can call t.someCommonMethod in here if you want
    ???
  }
}

object M1 {
  def doSomething(something: Something): Something = {
    M2.someComputation(something)
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that answers your question but hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see how does this answer my question.  in particular, the problem is the difference between M1.Program and M2.Program and how to treat these uniformly